# List of valid suid/sgid executables?

Tags: 14.04, users

Can anyone tell me where to find a list of valid suid/guid programs on Ubuntu (14.04)?

Note I can use find to get a list of suid/sgid programs on my machine, but I want to know if they are real valid programs; is there a list I can compare them against or some other means to determine if they are valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea - but will need a bit of work in scripting --- be my guest ;-)

1. Find a suid/sgid file; let's call it `scommand`
2. Check from which package has been installed:

   ```
   dpkg -S /full/path/to/scommand
   ```
3. Compare its permission with the original deb package, by firstly downloading the package:

   ```
   apt-get download package
   ```
4. Check if the command should have the suid set in the package with

   ```
   dpkg -c package*deb | grep /full/path/to/scommand
   ```
5. cleanup, rinse, repeat.

Example:

```
[romano:~/tmp] % ls -l /bin/passwd
ls: cannot access /bin/passwd: No such file or directory
[romano:~/tmp] 2 % ls -l /usr/bin/passwd
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 47032 Feb 17  2014 /usr/bin/passwd
[romano:~/tmp] % dpkg -S /usr/bin/passwd
passwd: /usr/bin/passwd
[romano:~/tmp] % apt-get download passwd
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main passwd amd64 1:4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9 [755 kB]
Fetched 755 kB in 1s (487 kB/s)
[romano:~/tmp] % dpkg -c passwd*.deb| grep /usr/bin/passwd
-rwsr-xr-x root/root     47032 2014-02-17 03:42 ./usr/bin/passwd
```

**caveat**: it can happen that a file is not suid/sgid in the .deb package and that it is changed so by the installation/post-installation scripts. In that case you have to find other ways to check, maybe comparing with a fresh installation.

Comment: I think this answers my question but I would have thought (and hoped) there was a simpler method, perhaps a published list of common suid/sgid programs.

Comment: I can share a list of mine, no problem... ;-) but that's hardly a authoritative answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:
It first does an apt-cache search for every package the system can download, then downloads them all (compressed in their .deb), then loops over each file running dpkg -c to get the path and permissions of the files in the .deb files by cutting out the first three characters and looking for the suid bit to be set at the start of the line, then prints all the paths that have suid attributes.

```
PKG=$(apt-cache search . | cut -f 1 -d ' ');
echo $PKG | xargs apt-get download;
F=(`find *.deb`); for i in ${F[@]};
do dpkg -c $i | cut -c 4- | grep ^s | cut -c 4- | cut -f 2 -d '.'  | tee > suid_root;
done
```

**Note:** this takes a *lot* of disk space to run, and isn't very optimized for speed or anything.